# Nondimensionalization of given equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-biology

I have the following equation, which is a logistic system with a death term, $$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-N/k)-p(N),$$ where $p(N)=\frac{BN^2}{A^2+N^2},$ for unknown constans $A,B$. I want to nondimensionalice the equation with a change of variables. I tried the typical change of variables for the nondimensionalization of the simple logistic equation, but i'm not being able to manage with $A$ and $B$. Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Hint: if $N$ is dimensionless so is $A$ but, as each term in the ODE has dimension $\mathsf{T}^{-1}$ (as does $r$), so does $B$. Now define $\tau:=rt,\,\beta:=B/r$.

Comment: I tried to apply this but i didn't end with nothing dimensionless. Could you please elaborate more in an answer?

Comment: So you didn't get this?$$\frac{dN}{d\tau}=N(1-N/k)-\frac{\beta N^2}{A^2+N^2}$$Please edit what you tried & got into your question.

Comment: Yeah i got exactly this! But there is no option to simplifie more the equation like in the lotka volterra model?

Comment: Everything's already dimensionless at that stage, unless you think $N$ isn't, in which case you could always take $N=An,\,k=A\kappa$ then suitably redefine $\beta$ so the ODE loses $A$. (You could eliminate $k$ instead of $A$ if you prefer.)

Comment: Well N is the population of some species so it has dimensions